# вставить тег в Nav widget

Tags: yii2

Хочу вставить в item виджета Nav тег span пытаюсь это сделать так

```
['label' => 'Корзина ' . Html::tag('span',$itemsInCart ? " ($itemsInCart)": '',['id'=>'itemsCounter']), 'url' => ['/cart/list'],],
```

меню соответсвтенно выдает мне вот такое Корзина  (11) как мне вывести тек в меню виджета Nav

Comment: а что хотите получить-то? у вас сейчас получается (11) в span с id=itemsCounter, вроде все как заказывали

Comment: Вам нравится кнопка меню вида Корзина <span id="itemsCounter">(11)</span> причем именто текст такой но я уже решил вопрос.

Comment: А, вы бы так и уточнили сразу, а то Корзина (11) смотрится вполне норм) С 'encodeLabels' => false да, есть такой момент.

Comment: @kroder оформляйте ответ подтвержу. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значит проблема в том, что по дефолту в Yii виджетах label проходят через HTML-енкод и любые html теги будут распечатаны как текст. Поэтому если в тексте лейблов нужна html верстка, то надо выставлять у виджета свойство `'encodeLabels' => false`.